# How to delete specific values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
my_list = 
[['UK', 'Manchester City', 'Blue', '1','2','B'],
['ES', 'FC Barcelona', 'Blue', '2','1','C'], 
['IT', 'Juventus', 'White', '3','2','A'],
['DE', 'Borussia Dortmund', 'Yellow', '4','1','A']]
```

Now I want to edit `my_list` and actually delete the values in index`0`,`3`,`4` and `5`.

**This is my expected output:**

```
  my_list = 
[['Manchester City', 'Blue'],
['FC Barcelona', 'Blue'], 
['Juventus', 'White'],
['Borussia Dortmund', 'Yellow']]
```

**This is the code I tried:**

```
for list in my_list:
    for idx in [0,3,4,5]:
        del list[idx]       
        
print(my_list)
```

**This is the output I get:**

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: You get an exception because you try to change the length from a list (del) inside to a for loop.

Comment: Why is my question disliked and deleted?

Comment: Marked as duplicate and it's not dislike .... it's downvote :)

Comment: I don't agree, I would not have posted this question If I could already have found the answer on SO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: @G.Mich come one men... I have a nested list thats different then the answers I found here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
my_list = [['UK', 'Manchester City', 'Blue', '1', '2', 'B'],
           ['ES', 'FC Barcelona', 'Blue', '2', '1', 'C'],
           ['IT', 'Juventus', 'White', '3', '2', 'A'],
           ['DE', 'Borussia Dortmund', 'Yellow', '4', '1', 'A']]

new_list = [lst[1:3] for lst in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

output

```
[['Manchester City', 'Blue'], ['FC Barcelona', 'Blue'], ['Juventus', 'White'], ['Borussia Dortmund', 'Yellow']]
```

Comment: What if I had to delete for example index `0`, `2` and `4`?

Comment: @NorthAfrican In this case the code would be different.

Comment: Can you show how it would be?

Comment: @NorthAfrican see https://pastebin.pl/view/813a1d04. Feel free to up vote.

Comment: I dont see any code when I click that link....

Comment: @NorthAfrican try https://pastebin.pl/view/2c72de92

Comment: Thank you, can you explain to me what you did in a private chat?

Comment: @NorthAfrican Start by reading the code few times. For the lines that you dont understand look around in the internet. If by the end of the process you will still have questions you can ask in stackoverflow.

Comment: thank you my Indonesian brother :)